# need to filter rows present in one dataframe on another

Tags: python, pandas

I have two data frames in pandas from which i need to get the rows with all the corresponding column values in second which are not in first .
ex

```
df A
A B C D 
6 4 1 6   
7 6 6 3
1 6 2 9   
8 0 4 9 
1 0 2 3 
8 4 7 5
4 7 1 1 
3 7 3 4 
5 2 8 8 
3 2 8 8 
5 2 8 8

df B
A B C D
1 0 2 3
8 4 7 5
4 7 1 1 
1 0 2 3 
8 4 7 5 
4 7 1 1 
3 7 3 4 
5 2 8 8 
1 1 1 1
2 2 2 2
1 1 1 1
```

req

```
A B C D
1 1 1 1
2 2 2 2
1 1 1 1
```

i tried using  pd.merge and inner/left  on all columns but it is taking a lot more computational time and resource if the rows and columns are more. is there any other way to work it around like iterating through each row of dfA with dfB on all columns and then pick the ones which are there only in dfB?

Comment: Can you post your attempt?  Can you also clarify what "not working" means?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `merge` with `ind` parameter.

```
df_b.merge(df_a, on=['A','B','C','D'], 
           how='left', indicator='ind')\
    .query('ind == "left_only"')\
    .drop('ind', axis=1)
```

Output:

```
    A  B  C  D
9   1  1  1  1
10  2  2  2  2
11  1  1  1  1
```